# How to write a wah-wah sound effect in C++?

Tags: c++, audio

I'm trying to learn to write a wah-wah sound effect. Just for fun really :)

So far, I've done a lot of research, and this page explains it the best. http://www.geofex.com/Article_Folders/wahpedl/voicewah.htm

Basically, I'm just looking for any simple C++ examples to generate a Wah-wah (ooaaooaa) effect.

Eventually once this is done, I hope to be able to also create a "eeeoooeeeoo" effect, or a "eeaaeeaa" effect :) Sort of vowel sythnthesis, but for music.

If I find any good examples I'll link to them here.

...

I'm having trouble with the mathematical side of things.

What waves do I need to generate to make an "E" sound? What waves do I need to generate to make a "O" sound?

I did try making two frequencies, with harmonics, according to that page, and adjusting the two frequencies, but it still sounded like electronic beeps, not vowels.

...

http://www.acoustics.hut.fi/publications/files/theses/lemmetty_mst/chap3.html This seems good. There are some numbers I can use. Hopefully it will sound "vowelish".

EDIT: I tried making some sounds at those frequencies mentioned on the page (100hz,600hz,1000hz,2500hz). It did not sound "vowelish". Maybe very slightly, but not properly.

So obviously I need to do more frequencies to make a proper "a" sound. Although I'm not sure WHAT frequencies.

I COULD just record my own voice. And then maybe download some otherpeople speaking vowels. And then find a spectrum analyser app. But I tried searching for a spectrum analyser app, and the first one I found wouldn't work on sound files just microphone input. Seems like it will be a lot more work trying to find a spectrum analyser app that does what I need. I might need to write my own.

Shame I can't find a resource with a list of requencies to generate a certain vowel from... just so I can LEARN from this. And then using that knowledge, develop a "vowel filter" that works like a wahwah but with "ioio" or "eaea" sounds.

Right now, the amount of effort I need to do:

- download good vowels
- test perhaps 4 apps to see if it can analyse frequency spectrums from a file
- generate the frequencies from that spectrum
- test the frequencies to see if it sounds "vowel-like"

Its not really "fun" anymore. Its work. Shame. As I have other (real) work to be doing. I'll park this one until I find enough answers that will make this project fun to work on.

Comment: I would be amazed if someone could write a sound anywhere.

Comment: This is going to be platform dependent. What platform are you on/targeting?

Comment: Easiest method would be to write a C++ program, and then accidentally overwrite it with a voice recording with a new microphone.

Comment: Not necessarily platform dependent. You can use something like PortAudio or libsndfile if you don't want to write a plugin.

Comment: Right now, I'm just writing a .wav file. I'm only generating sounds right now, not altering incoming sounds. Once I understand how to generate an "e" or "o" or "a" sound, I'll know more about how to filter sounds to make them sound like vowels :)

Answer (score 3):

About sounding like vowel, you should look at the [Formants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant).
They help very much in synthesizing voice.

Passing your sound thru a Formant filter may lead precisely to the effect you want.

EDIT: I insist a Formant filter **IS NOT** a wah-wah effect. A Wah-wah effect is only a simple bandpass filter. A formant filter is more complex.

Comment: I'm trying to make a Formant filter. I want to understand this thing myself, not just use some one else's premade stuff :) I'm doing this for fun, not work.

Comment: I don't understand your comment ? because the wah-wah effect in itself is **not** a formant filter. Its only a pass-band filter. Much Much Much simpler. I mean they are -for me- almost unrelated. Hence my answer.

Comment: I advise you this book so as to start in computing music. "The Computer Music Tutorial  - Curtis Road".

Comment: and "Elements of Computer Music - F. Richard Moore" for some good example of algorithms

Comment: and "music-dsp mailing list" to ask your deeply dsp related question.

Comment: A formant filter is a series of 2 or more parallel bandpass filters.